# Что делать с дублированными вопросами?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, дубликаты

Имеется [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499483/notifydatasetchanged-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (уже удален), который является просто копией уже существующего вопроса.

При этом на оригинальный вопрос нет принятого ответа( то есть вопрос такой уже задавался , но ответа на него нет), такие вопросы нужно помечать тревогой `повтор`

> "Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ"

или какой то другой?

Comment: если вопрос является дубликатом, его нужно пометить как дубликат

Comment: @Grundy То есть в описании "и на него уже есть ответ" -- не верно ?

Comment: конкретно в данном случае стоит вообще удалить данный вопрос, так как он ничего не спрашивает, а только привлекает внимание к предыдущему вопросу

Comment: @Grundy то есть помечать тревогой?  "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством У данного вопроса серьезные проблемы с форматированием или содержанием. Поскольку маловероятно, что его удастся улучшить с помощью правок, этот вопрос нужно удалить. "

Comment: да, я, например, пометил тревогой с причиной требуется внимание модератора

Comment: ну и в принципе модераторы оперативно сработали и удалили :)

Comment: @Grundy Ну вот теперь у меня нет примера)

Comment: Зря удалил, кстати, можно было просто приписку добавить, что типа уже удалено и доступно только для тех у кого много репутации :)

Comment: удалить худший из "похожих" вопросов :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если кто-то задает вопрос, чтобы обратить внимание на другой вопрос или просто многократно публикует одно и то же, то он явно не понимает модель работы Stack Overflow. Или понимает, но саботирует.

Отмечайте тревогой для модератора. Если располагаете временем и нервными клетками, то можете также оставить объясняющий комментарий или ссылку на справку.

Comment: А в случае если кто то другой задает аналогичный вопрос( к сожалению нет примера) на который нет ответа , является ли это дубликатом или нет?

Comment: @Batanichek, не важно _кто_ задает вопрос, важно - что находится в вопросе: дубликат - пометить дубликатом, призыв обратить внимание на другой вопрос - тревогу модератору. Ну либо всегда можно пройти мимо, либо ответить :)

Comment: То есть дубликат это любой дублирующий вопрос( не важно есть ли ответ на него или нет )?  может тогда стоит поправить описание "Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ"

Comment: @Batanichek, на вопрос _без_ ответа, если не ошибаюсь, система не даст поставить дубликат, а вот на вопрос, к которому есть ответ, но не принят, вроде можно.

Comment: @Grundy верно, на неотвеченный нельзя отметить дубликатом.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то нельзя целью дубля отметить вопрос, имеющий ответы, но без голосов за и без принятого. Т.е. ответы должны быть, и должны они быть либо заплюсованы, либо приняты

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это и есть "отвеченный" в терминах SO.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, мы то с вами это знаем, но посетители сего вопроса могут и не знать)